# how to send the java output in json format to html forms

Tags: javascript, java, html, json, ajax

I had wsdl link and used in java program to get the data in json format and how can use the json to send to the html forms to the display the data what are the technologies I want to use for this process can anyone please suggest me if you can.

Answer (score 0):

With json lib. You can check it on google.
And I dont know maybe you can use struts session.

Answer (score 0):

Gson can be best bet in your case.

> Gson is a Java library that can be used to convert Java Objects into
>   their JSON representation. It can also be used to convert a JSON
>   string to an equivalent Java object. Gson is an open-source project
>   hosted at http://code.google.com/p/google-gson.

Comment: after converting to java object what i need to do to get the data in html format

Comment: you have to render the data in html tags. It depends on what your front end is.
Is it JSP/Angular/bootstrap

Comment: can you give me some examples for this kind of applications

Comment: Angular works very well with JSON. You need to get good basics around fetching json data in Angular. I guess this can help . follow the [Link](https://www.baeldung.com/angular-js-rest-api) It is meant for REST API but the logic holds good for your case also.